# animation rig texture rendered error

Tags: texturing, uv, rigging, node-editor

i would be so thankful if anyone answer this question :D.
my mouth rig texture works fine in all viewport shading except at the rendered mode, it controls both my uv mesh which is the body part and the mouth part. i already seperate the uv map though. also the blue thingy on its cheek is a material not texture

the second image is the screenshot that in rendered mode all texture move

this is the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zQYTiwJJUyOXO7Jzk1i7wuOw5QjZFr-X/view?usp=sharing

thank you for the response:D

[image]

[image]